# How to modify data to make box plot?

Tags: microsoft-excel, r, statistics

My data is formatted like:

```
    0:01:11 0:01:58 0:01:12 0:01:33 0:01:14
    0:01:07 0:07:00 0:04:14 0:02:07 0:03:06
    0:01:16 0:01:00 0:02:39 0:03:00 0:03:43
    0:02:26 0:02:57 0:08:43 0:03:10 0:01:58
```

The values are not time units but are text. It is actually a time difference but the way our software gives me the table is in text format. The numbers are *h:mm:ss*.

Can I manipulate it to make a box plot, based off columns? I have tried numerous options, and I have no issue calculating *MIN, Q1, MED, Q3, MAX*. I have even attempted to utilize R, but the colons are messing it up.

Thank you

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Utilized this piece of formula to satisfy issue:

```
 =(PageName!A2-INT(PageName!A2))*1440
```